# Changing working directory in Erlang shell under Windows

Tags: erlang

I have Erlang installed on my WinXP machine. Becouse so, I use it by a "werl.exe". The problem is, that I would like to change a default folder that werl starts in. I cannot find option that would let me do that, although I know there must be something like that.
Could anybody help ?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to change directory at run time in the emulator then use the built in function cd as below..

```
72> cd("c:/Sandbox/erl").
c:/Sandbox/erl
ok
```

Note: You need to use the forward slash and not backward slash as you would normally do in windows.

Comment: That's what I was missing. I needed the quotes

Answer (score 12):

- You can specify initial settings in a `.erlang` file
- It should be located C:\Program Files (x86)\erlX.X.X\usr.erlang (where X.X.X is the version number...)
- If there isn't any then feel create one (note: you'll likely need to run your editor with administrative privileges to create the .erlang file in the appropriate location).
- Here is a simple example for the content:

  ```
  io:format("C:/Program Files (x86)/erl5.10.4/usr/.erlang\n").
  io:format(" ______      _                   \n").
  io:format("|  ____|    | |                  \n").
  io:format("| |__   _ __| | __ _ _ __   __ _ \n").
  io:format("|  __| | '__| |/ _` | '_ \\ / _` |\n").
  io:format("| |____| |  | | (_| | | | | (_| |\n").
  io:format("|______|_|  |_|\\__,_|_| |_|\\__, |\n").
  io:format("                            __/ |\n").
  io:format("                           |___/ \n\n").
  shell_default:cd("C:/Documents/MyErlangProjects").
  ```
- Notice the use of *nix-like forward-slashes (i.e. "/") rather than the typical Windows convention of using back-slashes (i.e. "\").
- It can be tested by running an erlang shell and on startup it will print this cool ASCII stuff :).  *Beware, the cool ascii stuff doesn't mean a valid working directory was specified!*
- Of course the main important line is the last one:
  `shell_default:cd("C:/Documents/MyErlangProjects").` where you specify which directory you want to start with as the current working directory.

Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you very much, although, you solution is good to change working directory for all projects. I wanted something, that could make easy to change working directory for every project separatly.
Although, as I said, it's nice tip so thank you for that :)

Comment: The location of the `.erlang` file is `c:\users\<username>\.erlang` in my windows 10 / erlang 10.7.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you all.
It was just as easy as typing a desired path in the "Start in" option in the "preferences" of shortcut to werl.exe.

Comment: Works for Elixir too - I put a windows short cut in the code directory and alter the "Start In" options. Thanks Zbigniew!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run Erlang in many different projects in different directories I found the easiest most basic solution is to create separate `.bat` files in each directory. Clicking on one will then run Erlang in the right directory. This makes it easy to set environment variables for Erlang, `ERL_LIBS` is a good one. It also makes it easy to use different versions at the same time, one `.bat` file for each version.